# Extracting (human) names from a description

Tags: python, nlp

I'm writing a piece of software that processes TV guide listings and converts them to XMLTV.

I've noticed that a lot of my descriptions contains who hosts the show - and I would like to be able to extract that information.

One of the methods I first looked at was regex, however my regex skills aren't great, and there doesn't seem to be a great way to achieve it anyway.

Another option is NLP, however that seems to be a bit over the top for what I need, especially since my descriptions share a common prefix (Hosted by). However, this may be the method I will go with, as it could be the most reliable and easy to use.

For reference, here is an example dataset - some are real, some are made up.

```
['Hosted by Jim Bolger, John James and Jim Bob, The Project is a show that exists',
'Hosted by Lisa Owen, Newshub Nation is an in-depth weekly current affairs show focusing on the major players and forces that shape New Zealand.',
'A fast paced wrap of all things entertainment, celebrity and Bravo hosted by Cassidy Morris',
'Hosted by chef Guy Fieri, Minute To Win It sees competitors take on a series of seemingly simple tasks while under a one-minute time limit.',
'Hosted by Jim van de Allen, Tom Scott and Petra Grazing, this is fair go',
'Hosted by Zyon Zickle, Johnny Boi and Zippy De Phrasee, The News looks at the important things that affect all Martians',
'Lorem is a magical substence wondered about by generations of things. This series hosted by Jim Tokien, explores this thingie']
```

I would much rather quality over quantity - so I'd rather it find less that matches, but most of the matches to be accurate rather than a lot of inaccurate matches.

Am I overthinking this? Is there a simpler way to do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it.

Comment: Well, do you want to consider `'chef Guy Fieri'` a human name? Or `'Zyon Zickle'` without his cohosts? If not, what's the rule that tells you otherwise? If you think there's an intuitively obvious answer but can't come up with a rule, NLP or generic machine learning _may_ help, but they are both pretty over the top. If you don't think there's an obvious right answer, the problem is basically impossible. But if you can come up with a rule, the first step is to explain that rule clearly—and then turning it into code shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Basically the rule is like this. Hosted by [Person A], [Person B] and [Person C], or for one person Hosted by [Person A] - it will always have `Hosted By`, `and` for 2 or more and commas for 3 or more. I would consider both of them human names - the biggest issue is I don't want this to accidentally pick up the show names, e.g. `The Project` or `The News`.